moov atom not found [in#0 @ 0x62ea0f9fb500] Error opening input: Invalid data found when processing input
I'm trying to convert an MP4 video, created using OpenCV, to HLS format using FFmpeg. However, I keep encountering the following error:
moov atom not found [in#0 @ 0x62ea0f9fb500] Error opening input: Invalid data found when processing input.
FFmpeg Command:
ffmpeg -i input_file_path -r 30 -g 60 -keyint_min 60 -sc_threshold 0 
-c:v libx264 -preset veryfast -profile:v main -level 4.0 
-hls_time 2 -hls_list_size 0 -hls_flags delete_segments+append_list+split_by_time+omit_endlist 
-hls_segment_filename segment_%03d.ts hls_output_path
Python Code for Creating MP4:

import cv2
import tempfile
import os
from subprocess import call

with tempfile.NamedTemporaryFile(delete=False, suffix='.mp4') as temp_file:
    raw_filename = temp_file.name
    fourcc = cv2.VideoWriter_fourcc(*'H264')
    out = cv2.VideoWriter(raw_filename, fourcc, fps, (width, height), True)

    out.write(cv2.cvtColor(first_frame, cv2.COLOR_RGB2BGR))
    for frame in frame_generator:
        out.write(cv2.cvtColor(frame, cv2.COLOR_RGB2BGR))

    out.release()

with tempfile.NamedTemporaryFile(delete=False, suffix='.mp4') as temp_file:
    final_filename = temp_file.name

command = [
    'ffmpeg',
    '-y', 
    '-i', raw_filename,
    final_filename
]
call(command)

with open(final_filename, 'rb') as file:
    video_bytes = file.read()

os.remove(raw_filename)
os.remove(final_filename)

Environment:
OS: Ubuntu
Cloud: AWS EC2
FFmpeg Version: 6.1.1-3ubuntu5

Are you using openCV for reasons beyond writing data? If not, what's the data format of frame's and first_frame? Numpy arrays?
